# return to the main app which launched my custom app

Tags: iphone

My app handles certain file types, like pdf. When pdf files are encountered in other apps say mobile safari, it lists my app in the "open-with" list. If my app is chosen to handle the pdf file, how do I get back to the main app, mobile safari in this case, after I am done with the task ?

In general, how do I fall back to the main app from where my app was started/launched ?
Is there some way to notify them to resume, after I am done ?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I fall back to the main app from where my app was started

You don't, the user needs to navigate back themselves to safari (if they want to).